# Bootstrap sidebar collapsing/making active multiple items with a common destination (href) prefix

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First, I tried to make a bootply/jsfiddle, but since the problem is when I click on an anchor, I couldn't reproduce the issue.

Here's what is wrong, I have a two-level collapsible bootstrap sidebar. I also use metisMenu.js to make it accordion-like, but the issue is when I click a link and the page reloads.

I have a couple of links in the sidebar, some have a common prefix and when I click one of these, the links with a common prefix get collapsed.

So let's say I have a menu with some items:

```
<div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
 <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav" id="admin-menu">
     <li>
       <a href="/admin">
          admin
       </a>
     </li>


     <li>
        <a href="#">...</a>
        <ul class="collapse nav nav-second-level">
            <li>
               <a href="/admin/search">
                  admin/search
               </a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="/admin/search/something">
                 admin/search/something
               </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

jsfiddle just to show, it doesn't work since we need links: http://jsfiddle.net/87fhfys2/2/

If I click the `admin` link, it is set as active, `...` is not collapsed.

If I click `admin/search`, `admin` is set as active, `...` is collapsed and `admin/search` is also active.

If I click admin/search/something all three links are active and `...` is also collapsed.

Is there any way I can remove this behavior? Instead of checking for prefixes check if the entire link matches?

Comment: Ok, I just threw this SB Admin 2 template and MetisMenu in the trash. I'm using another template with manual data-collapse and chevron arrows managing, it is kind of ugly but works flawlessly. This is also a good alternative:  http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-navigation-menu

Comment: Hi hfingler, I'm not quite sure if the problem you were experienced was the extra repaint in each menu. But just in case check this solution, it takes out the extra repaint in the second-level menus https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/issues/18